# Does "This edit is incorrect or an attempt..." mean the edit contains misinformation?

Tags: discussion, edits

(There seem to be a few questions in this vein, but I found conflicting answers, so I'll go ahead and ask.) Does the rejection reason

```
This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.
```

mean that there was some technical misinformation in a proposed edit? The wording is unclear to me.

Comment: It could be technical misinformation, or it could be an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post. Both are reasons to reject a suggested edit as incorrect.

Comment: If your question is about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/318758), the reason was probably that the reviewer considered it as a comment on the post. The other reviewer chose `radical change`, which seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @DanielFischer That prompted me to try and understand exactly what the reject comment means; since I found conflicting answers, I decided to ask about the comment in general. (Also, nice background check haha.)

Comment: Matthew, the sad truth is that different reviewers have different ideas about what edits should be rejected and why. Also most of the time one picks one of the canned reasons and chooses one that sort-of-fits. I think the most correct rejection reason for that one would have been a custom reason: "This should be an answer on its own (after slightly expanding it)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can mean various things that are subjective based on the person who rejected the edit. Usually it means someone tried to edit the post to add a comment or question, when that should have been placed in its own comment instead of editing the post. But I assume that some reviewers just read the first four words and choose that reason over "invalid edit" when the edit is actually wrong (e.g. correcting "Wrod" to "Wdor" when it should have been "Word") or, as you suggest, introduces incorrect information.

Comment: Any particular reason "incorrect information" and "should be a comment" are lumped together?

Comment: @MatthewAdams Editing an attempt to reply to a post into the post itself is incorrect.

Comment: @MatthewRead This newbie finds that confusing. I get what you're saying, but it seems more intuitive to separate "Some/All of the information you added in this edit is technically incorrect" and "Per SO rules, edits should not be replies". Granted I'm still trying to learn the system.

Comment: @MatthewAdams we could probably have 50 different rejection reasons, but I think consolidation makes sense. I shouldn't have to choose between 50 reasons and think that hard every time I reject an edit. If you have an edit rejected and you disagree with it, you can always post here. Because different people have different perception on the definition of a rejection reason, even if we had 50 choices you still might not have been given the correct reason.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Totally agree that 50 different reasons would be unmanageable, and people probably shouldn't be forced to explicitly type out a reason. I just wanted to let y'all know that this one is confusing to me and (I'd bet) other newbies who as well. It seems to me like the two broad reasons to reject an edit are "incorrect information" and "edit does not follow SO rules." Most rejects probably fall under subcategories of the latter category- eg. spam edits, too small edits, too large edits, changing the meaning, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The canned standard text is perhaps not totally clear, because it is used for both questions and answers. Sometimes the suggested edit tries to fix the bad code in the question, instead of writing a separate answer. That's the "or an attempt to reply" reason.

In your case, it is always a bit tricky when the suggested "fix" to the answer is much larger than the original answer. Like twice the size... That risks getting rejected because it changes too much or could really be a separate answer.

When I see a question with several short *how to* answers, I sometimes add a separate *why* answer as well. That is also answering  the question, but in a different way.

You should also consider that if your suggested edit is accepted, you get a +2 rep. If you write your own answer, and it is upvoted, you get +10 rep (each time).