# Confused by rejected edit suggestion deemed "incorrect or an attempt to reply...or comment"

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1974419) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/912831/1810429) that I voted up because it helped me resolve a StyleCop issue I bumped into this evening.  I suggested the edit because the question (and answer) are truly specific to a certain (subset of) StyleCop rule(s): the generality of the question's title nearly led me to miss it as an exact fit for the issue I encountered.

The edit was deemed "incorrect or an attempt to reply...or comment" and finally "too minor"; but neither reason for rejecting the suggested edit makes sense to me.

Is this an example of [quick reviews with too little understanding of the question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177161/219145)?  Was "incorrect or an attempt to reply...or comment" likely [just the easiest rejection reason to select moving quickly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140001/219145) - the suggested edit maybe being rejection-worthy for some other reason?  (Both surely happen, and I get that.  I just want to understand and hopefully learn something from this.)

Am I just alone in thinking my suggestion was appropriate to help someone searching see what the question and answer (don't) really address, also make the post a bit more readable at the same time? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we have users perpetually approving the wrong edits, I'm not surprised those same users are incorrectly rejecting proper edits as well.

That said, it may be worth pointing out that one of the reviewers (who's decidedly a good reviewer, not a bad one) chose the "too minor" reason for rejection. I'm not entirely sure if your edit could be much more substantial, but I can confidently say that there doesn't appear to be anything inherently *wrong* with your edit.

Comment: Thanks.  I resubmitted the edit.  Hey, moving quickly through many back-to-back code reviews strikes me as an analogous process...where I've certainly had plenty of first-glance misreads. :)

Comment: @J0e3gan: Welp, I didn't even get the chance to review it and it got approved by a different group of people. I may just organize a lynching for the first two rejecting users.

Comment: :) LOL  Eh, _sometimes_.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to edit lightly besides clarifying the nature of the question with the change to the title.  The question was well written, just the title being a little general; but I edited the question text a bit for readability while I was at it...ironically to keep the suggested edit from being deemed too minor. :)